# Optimize UITableViewCell thumbnail loading from CoreData

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am currently retrieving my UITableViewCell thumbnail images from CoreData. It is a 2k maximum png.

It is working fine actually, and user didn't notice any slowness, but I would like to improve the mechanism avoiding too many CoreData request.

Infact the cell is loaded when needed, and this is fine, however the point is that a request to CoreData is always made for each cells that pass to display. A possible solution is to load thumbnail only when table view stop scrolling, but with this solution, the cell is displayed with a common shared image, because I have implemented prepareForReuse which actually reset the cell.

So, is there a simple way for caching CoreData images, I suppose in memory, and retrieve it ?

My Objective-c knowledge is still limited, so the quickest solution I can think of is an NSIndexPath.row->UIImage dictionary (my table has no sections), but I don't know if other simple and elegant solution can be implemented.

Comment: Infact, the persistent store ie. sqlite database is not queried each time you request for the data from the coredata. There is a mechanism called faulting in coredata which caches the object when it is first fetched. You would want to reset the context or refresh the object to instruct the core data to hit the database again. So, there is no problem since it is faulted as plain objects and you just need to make sure that you reset or refresh the object very less often.

Comment: So, it is unnecessary to use any caching mechanism, considering that I am retrieving the image as entity. In this case I would end up with two caches, mine and CoreData one, wasting more memory than needed. Am I understanding right ?

Comment: Well, core data is a permanent cache and you would not always fire sql query just to retrieve few images. Will you ? Also you are using image not more than 2k but if it is larger image then definitely saving in the local disk is a better approach. Even if you save the image in local disk, you would create UIImage object and then cache it some how. So, I dont think you are paying a huge penalty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems very simple and elegant to me. I can only point your attention to use NSCache instead of dictionary, fo various reasons. Auto removal is one of them, you can also set different removal policies, limit and many more (acces from different thread with no locking doesn't seem to fit your case). So this may save you just those few lines of code.

Comment: As you suggest I am using NSCache, easy to setup and use. I found great improvement, especially all flickering that were occurring time to time during table scroll are gone. However, because of table datasource changing, I had to implement a very little logic for cache  updating.

Comment: Great, I am glad I could help. There always is some custom logic to make. The trick is to get the right balance.